# Visual C++ isn't recognizing comment lines?

Tags: c, visual-c++, compilation, compiler-errors, stdio

My program's first line is:

```
/* Arquivo testaesparsas.c */
```

And,after compile it,I get those (and many others) error messages:

```
visual studio 2010\projects\matrizes esparsas\matrizes esparsas\testeesparsas.c(1): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'testaesparsas'

visual studio 2010\projects\matrizes esparsas\matrizes esparsas\testeesparsas.c(1): error C2059: syntax error : ';'

visual studio 2010\projects\matrizes esparsas\matrizes esparsas\testeesparsas.c(1): error C2059: syntax error : '.'

visual studio 2010\projects\matrizes esparsas\matrizes esparsas\testeesparsas.c(1): warning C4138: '*/' found outside of comment
```

Surprisingly, I found errors attached to native libraries (as stdio.h) among the errors's messages:

```
1>c:\arquivos de programas\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\stdio.h(245): error C2059: syntax error : ')'

1>c:\arquivos de programas\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\stdio.h(247): error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '__cdecl'

1>c:\arquivos de programas\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\stdio.h(247): error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier '_DstSize'

1>c:\arquivos de programas\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\stdio.h(247): error C2081: 'size_t' : name in formal parameter list illegal
```

What may be happening?

Comment: It's complaining about `;` when there isn't even that character in the line. I don't think you're compiling the file you think you are.

Comment: Comment says test **ae** sparsas, but errors say test **ee** parsas

Comment: Barmar,I am,in fact :/

Comment: @LB-- ,the word is "testaesparsas",but the archive's name is "testeesparsas.c"...don't think that's the point

Comment: Is the source file saved with a UTF-8 BOM header by any chance?

Comment: Have you included a header file which has C like comments? That might be causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> visual studio 2010\projects\matrizes esparsas\matrizes esparsas\testeesparsas.c(1): warning C4138: '*/' found outside of comment
> ```

This warning can be caused by trying to nest comments or if you type '*' before comment:

```
int */*comment*/ptr;
```

or

```
a = b */*comment*/c;
```